# Configuring EMR cluster, which node to choose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

Suppose I read data from RDS and write it into S3 using EMR cluster (Spark), should I use *Task* nodes only?

```
Example:
* 1 Master node 
* 4 Task nodes
```

In my case I don't use HDFS to store data, so that using *Core* node isn't necessary, if I understand it right. Or should I have at least one *Core* node in any way? Any ideas?

Comment: I think that a cluster requires at least one Core node.

Comment: The core nodes also host the EMRFS process, so you'll need at least one Core Node to talk with S3. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68078609/aws-emr-with-task-nodes-only-for-s3-emrfs-only-processing-and-1-core-node))

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, You should have **at least one core node.**

I also had a similar use case a very long time back, where I had used Spark-SQL to read data from S3 and insert it into RDS (opposite of your use case, but that does not matter in any way).

Since the nature of this job was not heavy, I had **used only the Master node and Core node.** I did not use any Task node, since I did not find the need of using it for a small job.

I think it is a little misunderstanding that Only when HDFS is used, we should look towards usage of the Core node. The way I see it is at the end of the day, even core node is an instance where I can run an application.

So even the **Core node can perform the job of task/worker node** and I have seen multiple examples where the core node is of high instance type(say r5.24xlarge) and even on this instance your executors would be running.

In my above example, all the tasks were performed on the core node itself since I did not have any task node.

In my experience, I have seen a lot of EMR **which has only Master node and Core node.** Have **not seen anything with just the Master node and task node.**

One key point which I want to share is **Please use at least one on-demand instance in the core node.** You can have a fleet of instances in the core node(composed of both on-demand and spot), but having at least one on-demand node is highly advisable.

More readings can be found here:

1. [Understand Node Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-master-core-task-nodes.html)
2. [Cluster Configuration Guidelines and Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-instances-guidelines.html#emr-dev-core-instance-group-spot)

So the moral of the story is:

> should I have at least one Core node in any way?

Yes, You should in my opinion.

Comment: But what is the basic difference between core and task nodes? like how will or does it function when I have 20 gb of data. How is it distributed between core and task under the hood. Please help