# AWS EMR with Task Nodes only for S3/EMRFS-only processing and 1 Core Node

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, nodes, amazon-emr

Given that AWS with EMR provide you with their optimized Spark experience, then:

- If I am planning to only use S3 / EMRFS for both directly reading and directly writing and *not* using s3DistCP,

  - Why do I need at least 1 Core Node?

My suspicion is that at least 1 Core Node is needed to get around the issue of Spark shuffle files due to yarn dynamic  resource allocation being lost in the past when Core Nodes could be deallocated with scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to AWS personnel:

> Core nodes host the EMRFS/HDFS daemon. So you need at least 1 Core
> node to talk to S3 using EMRFS.

I got that myself, but add my suspicion is that at least 1 Core Node is also needed to get around the issue of Spark shuffle files - due to Yarn Dynamic Resource Allocation for Spark - being lost in the past when Core Nodes could be deallocated with scaling. Core Nodes cannot be deallocated after auto-scaling or initial allocation.

That said, I note that some 2 years ago a lot has gone into EMR Spark resilience: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-running-apache-spark-applications-using-amazon-ec2-spot-instances-with-amazon-emr/